# this.node showing itself as just #document-fragment in Chrome console

Tags: javascript, dom, polymer, shadow-dom

I read in Polymer's documentation:

> Every Polymer element has a this.root property which is the root of its local DOM tree.

(https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html)

If I have a simple element like this:

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="dom-test">
  <template>
    <div>
      <hr>
      <span id="something">Something</span>
      <p>This is the local DOM</p>
      <p>Adding the contents:</p>
      <content></content>
      <p>End of contents!</p>
      <hr>
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer( {
      is: 'dom-test',
      ready: function(){
        var self = this;
        console.log( this.root );

        SELF = self;

      }
    })
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

NOTE: I know that SELF is a global variable.
And then using the element in your .html file:

```
...
<link rel="import" href="dom-test.html">
...
<dom-test><p>SECOND</p></dom-test>
...
```

If I type `SELF.root` in the Chrome console, I only get `#document-fragment`.
Any attempt to query its contents don't work:

```
SELF.root.children
[]
```

Even more confusing, still in the documentation:

> Calling append/insertBefore adds the node to parent’s light DOM. In order to insert/append into the local DOM of a custom element, use a node in the local DOM as a parent (or this.root, which is the root of the local DOM).

Am I missing something? How can I get to *see* the element's LOCAL DOM in the Chrome console?

Answer (score -1):

Any DOM manipulations should be handled with Polymer.dom when dealing with Polymer's custom-elements. Source: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html#dom-api

```
Polymer.dom(SELF.root).children
```

It would also be better if you'd refer to the element outside it's declaration. So instead of declaring a global `SELF` variable to refer to the element, you should use `document.querySelector` or `document.getElementById` and work from there (aside from the fact that `SELF` would be rewritten every time you attach a `dom-test` element to the DOM).

Comment: The question is clear... "How can I get to see the element's LOCAL DOM in the Chrome console?"?

Comment: (That SELF was obviosuly just there so that I could get to it from the console...)